# SignalR 0.5.3 and IIS 7.5

Tags: iis-7.5, signalr, windows-server-2008-r2, signalr-hub

I have an application already deployed on a couple of customers utilizing signalr for communication. It works on windows 2003 server with IIS 6.0 with the mappings configuration, also works on win 7 and iis express. But for windows 2008 R2 with IIS 7.5 the hubs file although it's served, the signalr.hub with the list of server methods is NOT included in the script therefore clients can't connect to the hub.

Help is appreciated!!!

Comment: Just to clarify: /signalr/hubs does not contain your hub? Does the response contain anything or is it empty? If empty, is there a folder named /signalr/hubs on this machine?

Comment: When I hit /signalr/hubs a script file is served. This script file basically contains some signalr methods (makeProxyCallback, createHubProxies, invoke, etc) and the definition of the hub with the list of methods that are actually defined on the server. E.g: signalR.hub = { ... 

processConnection: function (userInfo) {
            return invoke(this, "ProcessConnection", $.makeArray(arguments));
        }
}..

the signalR.hub... blah blah blah is not being included in this file when I have on win 2008 r2 and iis 7.5

Comment: I'm sorry, I was just looking for clarification. But I do not have enough knowledge on this subject to help you on this, other than it runs on our similar environment (win 2008 r2 and iis 7.5). I guess you need to attract attention of damian-edwards or @dfowler...

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so here is what I found. We have a setup project that installs our product. I haven't looked into the process in detail but what it does is: creates a website under iis default, then assigns an app-pool that runs with Frw 4.0 and I think it also registers the framework at some point of the process. So, for some reason the javascript hub file was being generated without the actual definition of the hub. After so many teaks I decided to remove the website from iis and added it back manually and it got fixed. So, I don't know what setting was impeding signalr to initiate the hub but that was how I solved it.

Thanks